# Angular router configuration with path: '**' not working as expected in AWS S3

Tags: angular, angular-router

I am doing something very simple. I am hosting an Angular app on AWS S3.

The app is the simplest in the world, one home page with some static content.

The router is defined as follows

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'home',
    component: HomeComponent,
    data: { title: 'Home' }
  },
  { path: '',
    redirectTo: '/home',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  { path: '**', component: HomeComponent }
];
```

When I ask for the base url `http://my-site.s3-website.xxx.amazonaws.com/` I get the expected home page.

On the browser I see the the url `http://my-site.s3-website.xxx.amazonaws.com/home`, i.e. with the trailing `home` as expected looking at the router configuration.

If later I ask for the url `http://my-site.s3-website.xxx.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/home` I get again the expected Home page.

The problem raises when I enter a wrong url, such as `http://my-site.s3-website.xxx.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/homeac`, i.e. if I make a mistake and ask for `homeac` rather than `home`.

Considering that I have set in the routes, as last, the following rule

```
{ path: '**', component: HomeComponent }
```

I was expecting to retrieve again the Home page (i.e. the only page of the app). Rather I do not see anything on the browser and in the browser console I see the following error stack

[image]

When I do the same thing with the local development server (i.e. the one provided by `ng serve`) I do not get any error and the home page is correctly retrieved even is I use a wrong url.

Any idea about what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried with: { path: '**', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' }

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
{ path: '**', redirectTo: '/home'}
```